# Trying to run "npm run devStart" on mac

Tags: node.js, npm

This is my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "devStart": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

When trying to run npm run devStart on visual studio code terminal for mac I get the following errors

```
% npm run devStart
npm ERR! Missing script: "devStart"
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     npm restart # Restart a package
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
...
```

Comment: Could you add an output of `npm run` command as suggested in the error trace.

Comment: Can you share your folder structure? Are you sure you're looking to the right package.json? Make sure you're trying to run the command from the folder where your package.json is located at

Comment: If you're actively editing your `package.json` file, make sure you've saved changes